# What is the best practices to archive json documents to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I need to archive obsolete data from NoSql storage into Azure Blob storage and cannot find the way to do it: whether save it as json-files in Blolb storage or save it in Tables.

Key points: documents won't be modified, but they may be requested by name (ex. name is identifier).

UPDATE1:

1. All documents has unique names (GUID with salt).
2. Estimated documents number is about one million.

Comment: Will the name be unique across all documents? How big are these documents? Please edit your question and provide more details like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that: documents won't be modified, but they may be requested by name. Then you should store them in blob store.

In blob storage, there is a feature named [immutable storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage), you can set it and the blob will be read-only.